# What is the best way to associate multiple images to one page?

Tags: images, attachments

WP has one major problem and that's image handling. Each image is treated as a post and if you "attach" an image to a page, you cannot un-attach it.

Without installing a gallery plugin and without inserting them directly in the post, what is the best way to associate multiple images to a page / post?

Currently I create 5 custom fields if I want to attach max 5 images. It works, but it's not the best way.

Open to suggestions :)

Comment: I agree that image handling is horrible, but what do you want instead? How do you imagine things should work?

Comment: I would take a look at the new Projects theme by WooThemes. (in the repo). I think it is saving the attachment IDs as meta. I tried to build something similar 2 years ago but stalled out.

Comment: @s_ha_dum WP must completely stop treating any attachment as a post and develop a new file / image handler system. Until then, I just have to make do with whatever is at hand.

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) is a great solution - allows you to attach *anything* to your pages/posts/custom post types, great interface for setting it up, and very flexible. Good documentation as well.